# How to combine meta_query and date_query with condition in Wordpress

Tags: wp-query

I have a problem with the combination of meta_query and date_query.

I have meta_data with key is `start_time`. I want to query with the condition:

- if `start_time` is not empty then use with condition 'between', else `start_time` empty then use `post_date` instead with condition 'between'

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you familiar with writing your own SQL queries? I don't think `WP_Query` supports cases like "if is not empty"

Comment: kero is correct, this type of query is not possible with WP_Query. You could use SQL queries, but a better solution might be to address this when saving data, and ensure that start_time always has a value.

Comment: Thanks kero & Jacob. But if you want to do it with SQL Query, how should i do it? Because I can't figure it out yet.